# Handle a socket disconnect on server .NET C#

Tags: c#, sockets

In the event a user closes the application I have the following:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
}
```

When this happens my server triggers my Receive Callback routine. But there is no data.

Is there an existing method such as `OnDisconnect()` or `OnShutdown()` I can call in order for me to update my server and other clients?

Or should I add my own disconnect message prior to the shutdown command on the client?

Answer (score 0):

`Receive` returns zero when the connection was gracefully shut down. This is normal and must be deal with. Simply do nothing in the callback and clean up all resources.